# What's to be done about a wrong answer that is not edited or deleted?

Tags: discussion, review

Federico Fallucca's answer here contains an error [Set of branch points isn't discrete, but branch points are isolated?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813927/set-of-branch-points-isnt-discrete-but-branch-points-are-isolated/3813967#3813967)

as pointed out by Moishe Kohan

> what is written about branch points is plain wrong.

In general what is to be done when the community has not peer reviewed and the moderators decline your flag since flags are not factual inaccuracies besides downvoting, commenting and making a question like this?

---

Update 2: THE ANSWER IS DELETED! WOOHOO! THANKS EVERYONE!

---

Update 1: Seriously?

https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1484536

> amWhy reviewed this 15 mins ago: Reject and Edit

> Community♦ reviewed this 15 mins ago: Reject This edit did not correct critical issues
> with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been
> changed.

Comment: I won't put this as an answer as it's rather self-promoting, but this answer https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31674/why-did-this-answer-get-an-upvote/31675#31675 has some additional suggestions that you've not mentioned.

Comment: I feel like this has been brought up before, and I am going to keep looking for an appropriate dupe target, but, roughly speaking, leave a comment explaining the problem, flag it using a standard flag so that it gets sent into the review queue, and, if all else fails, mention it in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured).

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9314/

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks! What do you mean by 'flag it using a standard flag so that it gets sent into the review queue' ? I already tried flagging but declined as I mentioned...

Comment: Related: [Wrong answer is not corrected/deleted](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9314). A discussion related to deleting answers: [Should we vote to delete wrong answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27423) Since you have mentioned (mod) flags, some posts about (not) flagging incorrect answers:
[Is it in the Moderator's Job Description to patrol for correctness?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2473) and
[Don't flag wrong answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4731)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Holy cow!  Did I find a related link faster than you?!  (Or, as is more likely the case, did I just copy-paste faster than you could write a well thought out response?) :P

Comment: Do not use edits to correct the content of another answer.  And don't suggest that I support that post, just because I rejected the edit. (You posted a rather accusatory reply below the answer you complain about.  Edits are for correcting formatting, grammar, typos ... not to correct others submissions.) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813927/set-of-branch-points-isnt-discrete-but-branch-points-are-isolated/3813967?noredirect=1#

Comment: @amWhy 1 - you admit it's wrong but still don't remove it? 2  - i've edited for corrections for accuracies a lot already. this the 1st i'm hearing of this

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon If the answer is wrong, (1) leave a comment, (2) downvote it, (3) flag it using a standard flag (e.g. low-quality), and/or (4) mention it in CURED.  Editing it to change its meaning is inappropriate.

Comment: @Xander, Martin, could you please help me find previously stated positions on this matter?  Xander, you just recently summarized the position very very well.

Comment: @XanderHenderson **wait seriously?** the issue is that i submitted the *wrong flag* instead of that i submitted *a flag*?  'flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer'

Comment: One cannot vote to delete post while reviewing edits.  At the time of reviewal, the post had 0 net votes, and one can only vote to delete if it is in the low quality queue, or anytime it has a negative net score.

Comment: @XanderHenderson i posted your comment as an answer

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Flags are reviewed by the community, and are also sometimes reviewed by moderators.  Flags are not always handled in the manner you might like.  Which is why there are other options:  bring it up on CURED, leave a comment, or downvote.

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon Yes, I saw that you posted my comment as an answer.  You did this after I said that I was looking for a dupe target for this question, as it has come up before.  I must admit that I am not entirely happy with your actions. :\

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4731/dont-flag-wrong-answers

Comment: @XanderHenderson so why isn't this closed as a dupe yet? i don't see any votes yet

Comment: @amWhy Do you mean discussions of suggested edits used to correct an answer? Here is one question with such discussion: [Answer is wrong, suggested edit is right](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21148).

Comment: Update: THE ANSWER IS DELETED! WOOHOO! THANKS EVERYONE!

Comment: Yes, @Martin spot on.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wrong+answer

Comment: John, do not use ALL CAPS in posts nor in comments. On the internet, doing so amounts to shouting.

Comment: @amWhy But the all caps is for celebration not anger. Still don't even for celebration? You know like shouting for joy, hosanna in the highest, etc

Comment: John You're behaving in a somewhat immature way.   And you've been rather sarcastic about this issue.  Please review the Code of Conduct.  And start searching the question bank before duplicating. And start researching the Help Center, so you don't always  end up replying "That's news to me?!"

Comment: @amWhy I don't believe I've been sarcastic at all. I believe I've been extremely immature though.

Comment: Fair enough.  I take back the sarcasm charge, and agree with you that you've been "extremely immature".

Comment: @amWhy I get that a lot from family, friends, colleagues, etc, so you know. Yeah. thanks for the feedback even if i'm too stubborn to listen.

Comment: John:  Cheers! ;D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a moderator Xander Henderson♦

> roughly speaking, leave a comment explaining the problem, flag it using a standard flag so that it gets sent into the review queue, and, if all else fails, mention it in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured).